# vee-validate model-less validation on submit not working

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

this seems to be simple one but I can not get it work...

I want to validate if file is set only when I click the validate button. but the validation result in check method always return false.

```
<template>
  <ValidationObserver>
    <form @submit.prevent>
      <ValidationProvider
        ref="aProvider"
        name="file"
        rules="required"
        v-slot="{ errors }"
      >
        <input type="file" />
        <p>{{ errors[0] }}</p>
      </ValidationProvider>
      <button @click="check">validate!</button>
    </form>
  </ValidationObserver>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    async check() {
      const { valid } = await this.$refs.aProvider.validate();
      if (valid) {
        alert("Form has been submitted!");
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandbox-forked-6o7iyt?file=/src/Demo.vue

Comment: Since input not using v-model, you have to validate through @change event. 
https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/advanced/model-less-validation.html#html-file-validation

Comment: Validation onChange works fine. But I want to validate only when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The `validate()` method is for Observers, not for providers as specified in docs: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/guide/components/validation-observer.html#methods

Just set a `ref` on your Observer and run the method.

```js
<template>
  <ValidationObserver ref="form">
    <form @submit.prevent>
      <ValidationProvider
        name="file"
        rules="required"
        v-slot="{ errors }"
      >
        <input type="file" />
        <p>{{ errors[0] }}</p>
      </ValidationProvider>
      <button @click="check">validate!</button>
    </form>
  </ValidationObserver>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    async check() {
      const { valid } = await this.$refs.form.validate();
      if (valid) {
        alert("Form has been submitted!");
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I tired the code on codesandbox but this did not work. this.$refs.form.validate() always returns false.

Comment: Do you have any idea on this?

Answer (score -1):

Create a data property and bind it to the input via v-model. Move your ref to the ValidationObserver. Then it will validate properly.

Comment: Could you please provide an example with code snippet ? That would be more helpful for fellow developers.